# Counting True or False

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
    True_False
2018-01-02  True
2018-01-03  True
2018-01-04  False
2018-01-05  False
2018-01-08  False
... ...
2020-01-20  True
2020-01-21  True
2020-01-22  True
2020-01-23  True
2020-01-24  False
504 rows × 1 columns
```

I want to know how many successive `True` or `False` but not total it must stop counting after it toggles `True` or `False`. As such i want to eventually calculate `mean()`, `max()` and `min()` days. is it possible to show this data in Pandas?

Comment: What is expected output? `mean`, `max` and `min` is counts from some another column?

Comment: `mean`, `max`, `min` number of days of consecutive `True` and `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution if all datetimes are consecutive:

You can create helper `Series` for consecutive groups by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), then get counts by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
g = df['True_False'].ne(df['True_False'].shift()).cumsum()
s = df.groupby(['True_False',g]).size()
print (s)
True_False  True_False
False       2             3
            4             1
True        1             2
            3             4
dtype: int64
```

And last aggregate `min`, `max` and `mean` per first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
print (s.groupby(level=0).agg(['mean','max','min']))
            mean  max  min
True_False                
False          2    3    1
True           3    4    2
```

If datetimes are not consecutive first step is [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
df = df.asfreq('d')
g = df['True_False'].ne(df['True_False'].shift()).cumsum()
s = df.groupby(['True_False',g]).size()
print (s.groupby(level=0).agg(['mean','max','min']))
                mean  max  min
True_False                    
False       1.333333    2    1
True        3.000000    4    2
```

Comment: `g = df['True_False'].ne(df['True_False'].shift()).cumsum()`, i am getting `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`. I think this is because it is dataframe and needs to be converted to series?

Comment: it was `data1` and i just typed `data`. It is fixed ! Thanks